# How do i remove a a huge number of columns in a dataframe based on their number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has 60 columns. The names of the columns are years and are named 1960.0, 1961.0......2010.0. I want to remove the columns from 1960 to 2006. This is what i have tried so far:

```
     a = list(map(str,map(float,range(1960,2006))))
     gdp = gdp.drop(a,axis=1)
     gdp
```

When i run the code, it shows this:

`KeyError: "['1960.0' '1961.0' '1962.0' '1963.0' '1964.0' '1965.0' '1966.0' '1967.0'\n '1968.0' '1969.0' '1970.0' '1971.0' '1972.0' '1973.0' '1974.0' '1975.0'\n '1976.0' '1977.0' '1978.0' '1979.0' '1980.0' '1981.0' '1982.0' '1983.0'\n '1984.0' '1985.0' '1986.0' '1987.0' '1988.0' '1989.0' '1990.0' '1991.0'\n '1992.0' '1993.0' '1994.0' '1995.0' '1996.0' '1997.0' '1998.0' '1999.0'\n '2000.0' '2001.0' '2002.0' '2003.0' '2004.0' '2005.0'] not found in axis"`

I think that the \n are interfering here but i dont know how to make it work. Any help?
The heading of the columns are 1960.0, 1961.0,....2010.0. But it still doesnt work.

Comment: How working `gdp = gdp.drop(list(range(1960,2006)),axis=1)`

Comment: What is `print (gdp.columns.tolist())` before `gdp = gdp.drop(a,axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove floats, not strings, so removed converted to strings:

```
 a = list(map(float,range(1960,2006)))
 #or
 #a = list(range(1960,2006))

 gdp = gdp.drop(a,axis=1)
```

Or:

```
 gdp = gdp[:, ~gdp.columns.isin(a)]
```